# Settings button onClickListener

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onclicklistener

By default upon pressing the settings button in the action bar a small menu opens which contains one item  saying "settings". My question is if I can make the settings behave as a button, that is upon clicking it it doesn't open the small menu but does what I insert in the onClickListener.
Is that achievable?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html This will get you going in the right direction. You can decide what each item does when it is clicked on but as for changing what it does when clicking on the 'small menu' you refer to, you cannot change that. It's for storing MenuItems on a small screen.

Comment: @RED_ : in that case can I replace the settings button with a custom button of my own?

Comment: Possibly. You can create a custom action bar. You create the custom view in a layout file where you can add a button if you wish. Look into custom action bars. I would suggest sticking to the design guidelines. Just add a menuItem and have that do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no - you cannot treat it like you would treat a button. You could override your onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method to act as the equivalent of onClickListener() to get what you want.

Comment: by overriding the onOptionsItemSelected, the function only works for the items in the settings menu right? and not the settings button?

Comment: It will work for your settings menu item as well. I'm guessing you created the settings option as a menu item. All you have to do is do an if (item.getItemId == R.id.settings) {// logic goes here}.

Comment: The reason you see the settings item is because it is generated by default in an android project and you can see this under the menu folder in main.xml

Comment: I decided to chose the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) function after all :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have that, then you probably have something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I guess you could write whatever code you want to execute in there. Try to respect the Android way (the settings button should go to settings)